# authentication mode="Forms" login https to default http

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to use Forms Authentication to redirect from my login page (https) to my default page (http).

```
<forms name="mysite.com" loginUrl="https://www.mysite.com/Login.aspx" protection="All" defaultUrl="http://www.mysite.com/Default.aspx" requireSSL="false" timeout="30" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="UseCookies"></forms>
```

After a successfull login using:

```
Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.DefaultUrl, True)
```

The default page is still returned over https.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asp.net forms is not change the secure connection.

The better way to do that is to use ether yours code to switch from, ether an automatic module like this one:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/WebPageSecurity_v2.aspx